# Вывести номер документа и номер бланка документа без разделителей

Tags: sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу.

Есть 1 таблица, которая содержит номер документа и номера бланков, разделенные разделителем:

Таблица 1

```
----------
Doc_num blanks
----------
d1     b1/b2
----------
d2    b3
----------
d3    b4/b5/b6
----------
```

На основе этой таблицы необходимо вывести в отдельную таблицу, если такой-то номер бланка существует, вывести номер бланка и номер документа, соответствующий ему, т.е. если есть бланки b1, b2, то вывести их номера b1, b2 без разделителя и номер документа d1.

То есть должно быть так:

Таблица 2

```
----------
Blank doc
----------
b1   d1
----------
b2   d1
----------
```

Comment: Нормализация невозможна?

Comment: Нет, невозможна.

Comment: @demonicq2014, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Напишите табличную функцию, которая из вашей строки с разделителями сделает табличку с номерами. Используйте её для получения записей:

```
Insert tmp (did, bid) 
Select did, bid 
From tbl 
Cross apply dbo.fun (bids) tmp 
Where did in
(
    Select did 
    From tbl 
    Cross apply dbo.fun (bids) tmp 
    Group by did, bids
    Having count (bid) =
    (
        Select count (bid) 
        From dbo.fun (bids)
    )
)
```

**Обновление**

Работающий или нет, но все просто:

```
Create function dbo.fun (@bids nvarchar(max))
Returns @ret table (bid int) as begin 
With pos (start, length) as 
(
Select 1, isnull(nullif(patindex('%\%', @bids), 0), len(@bids) + 1) - 1
Where len(@bids) > 0
Union all 
Select start + length + 1, isnull(nullif(patindex('%\%', substring(@bids, start + length + 1, len(@bids))), 0), len(@bids) + 1) - 1
From pos 
Where start + length < len(@bids) 
)
Insert @ret (bid) 
Select convert(int, substring(@bids, start, length)) 
From pos 
Return 
End
```

Comment: Ну и да, если сохранить номера бланков в отдельную табличку, то можно сделать на несколько порядков быстрее.

Comment: Что такое cross apply и как написать табличную функцию? Можно работающий скрипт?

Comment: Работающий или нет, но все просто: 

Create function dbo.fun (@bids nvarchar(max))
Returns @ret table (bid int) as begin 
With pos (start, length) as 
(
Select 1, isnull(nullif(patindex('%\%', @bids), 0), len(@bids) + 1) - 1
Where len(@bids) > 0
Union all 
Select start + length + 1, isnull(nullif(patindex('%\%', substring(@bids, start + length + 1, len(@bids))), 0), len(@bids) + 1) - 1
From pos 
Where start + length < len(@bids) 
)
Insert @ret (bid) 
Select convert(int, substring(@bids, start, length)) 
From pos 
Return 
End